# Solve equation with lower gamma function: $A \gamma(2;x/B)=x$ for $x$

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

I need to find an expression for $x$ given:

$A \gamma(2;x/B)=x$

where $\gamma(a,x)=\int\limits_0^x t^{a-1} e^{-t} \mathrm{d}t$ is the lower incomplete gamma function. $A$ and $B$ are real, positive constants and $x$ should also be real and positive.

Mathematica is unable to solve this equation directly (neither Solve nor Reduce work). I have tried a Taylor expansion around $r=B$, but I don't get the desired convergence when $B \rightarrow 0$. This is important because eventually I'd like to get an expression valid when $r$ is of the order of magnitude of $B$, but that also reduces to $r=A$ when $B$ vanishes.

I've also tried writing the gamma function in terms of modified Bessel functions (http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7), but that didn't work either.

Would an asymptotic expansion work? In that case, what kind and how would I implement it? Also, where would it converge?

A second order approximation would be fine, but a numerical answer would not be ideal.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the obvious root $x=0$, are you sure there are others?

Comment: There are strong reasons to think so. This equation describes the radius of a black hole (x) in certain modified theory of gravity and I think there are some numerical solutions. Finding an expression for the black hole radius r is the reason why I need to solve this.

Comment: (But depending on A and B there could be no other solutions)

Comment: Okay, do you know of any particular values of $A,B$ where there are nonobvious solutions?

Comment: Just playing around plotting the equation it seems that A=2, B=.1 and r=2 work...

Comment: @misi by the way, definition of the incomplete gamma in Wolfram Mathematica is a bit different.

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache well, there are two kinds of incomplete gamma functions. This is the lower incomplete gamma function, you are probably looking at the upper version $\Gamma(a,x)=\int\limits_x^\infty t^{1-a} e^{-t} \mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: @misi Nope, in Wolfram Mathematica incomplete gamma is defined as follows: $\Gamma (a,z)=\int _z^{\infty }t^{a-1} e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t$. The difference from yours (original in the post) is not only in limits, but in sign of the power under the integral. I used the definition from [8.2.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2)

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache You are completely right! I didn't see the typo, sorry.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're interested in the equation $\gamma(2,x/B) = x/A$, where $\gamma(2,x/B) = \int_0^{x/B} t e^{-t}\,dt = 1 - e^{-x/B}(1+x/B)$?  It's simpler to replace $x/A$ with $y$, so the equation is $1 - e^{-y/B'}(1+y/B') = y$ with $B' = A/B$.  In the limit as $B' \to 0$ there are two solutions with $0 < y < 1$, one which tends to $0$ and one which tends to $1$.  Are you interested in both of them, or just the one where $y \to 1$ (i.e. $x \to A$)?

Comment: For example, using the method of bootstrapping we can show that the aforementioned solution of $\gamma(2,y/B)=y$ which tends to $1$ is $$y = 1 - \frac{1+B}{B}e^{-1/B} - \frac{1+B}{B^3}e^{-2/B} + O\left(B^{-4}e^{-3/B}\right)$$ as $B \to 0^+$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, hope this will be of any help (not solution, just thoughts).
$$A \gamma\bigg(2;\frac{x}{B}\bigg)=x$$
I'll call $a=\frac{A}{B}, \ z=\frac{x}{B}$, so  $a \gamma(2;z)=z$. Then I use the relation between incomplete gamma and confluent hypergeometric function $c z^c \gamma(c,z)=\mathrm{M}(c,c+1,-z)$, so, if we consider that $z\ne0$:
$$z \ \mathrm{M}(2,3,-z)=\frac{2}{a}$$.
$$\mathrm{M}(2,3,-z)=\frac{2 e^{-z} \left(-z+e^z-1\right)}{z^2}$$
$$\frac{2 e^{-z} \left(-z+e^z-1\right)}{z}=\frac{2}{a}$$
So (if I didn't loose anything)  I get the equation like this:
$$\frac{1}{a \ z}\bigg((1+z)e^{-z}+\bigg(\frac{z}{a}-1\bigg)\bigg)=0 $$
I guess starting here you can use series expansion or different approximations in cases of big/small arguments.
A [rough plotting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B-%28%28%28z-5%29%2b5%20E%5E%28-z%29%20%28z%2b1%29%29/%285%2az%29%29,%20%7Bz,0,10%7D%5D)(for example when $a=5$) shows that there should be some real positive roots.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. This is useful and might help me make numerical approximations. However, I'm still unable to find a closed expression, even an approximation, that is valid both when $x\rightarrow B$ and $B\rightarrow \infty$. I have reasons to think this might be impossible. It seems that any way I can come up with to effectively circumvent the gamma function ends up with something like $1+x e^x=x$ which I cannot solve. I'll open another question asking this.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is elementary:

$$\gamma(2;x)=\int_0^x te^{-t}dt=-\left.e^{-t}(t+1)\right|_0^x=1-e^{-x}(x+1).$$

Then, $$\frac xA+e^{-x/B}(x+1)=1,$$
which doesn't seem to be expressible with the Lambert function.